# Is there an alternative to logged batches on Amazon Keyspaces?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, amazon-keyspaces

Our team decided to move with Amazon Keyspaces from self hosted Cassandra. After configured with
Amazon Keyspaces I found that logged batches are not supported. In our solution there are multiple cases where it requires to use logged batches.

Ex:
We have few tables where we are propagating data, in order to have different primary keys for fast querying. Logged batches use here to maintain consistency in all tables.

Is there any alternative solution to this type of scenario in Amazon Keyspace ?

Comment: No, and there’s a whole list of other things that Keyspaces doesn’t support, too.  Not to self promote or anything, but if you want true managed Cassandra you can’t go wrong with DataStax Astra DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately with the lack of support for `LOGGED BATCH` in Amazon Keyspaces, you would somehow need to implement the logic within your application to keep the tables synchronised.

You would need to retry any failed updates to a table and if after N attempts it is still unsuccessful, you need to work out whether you need (a) issue deletes to the other tables, or (b) continue retrying.

It is unfortunate that you weren't aware of this limitation in Amazon Keyspaces. I would recommend familiarising yourself with other limitations in the following documents:

- [Functional differences with Apache Cassandra](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/functional-differences.html)
- [Supported Cassandra APIs, operations, functions, and data types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/cassandra-apis.html)

Comment: Actually, we were known about those issues. But as a team, we are fully migrating our products into AWS and thought, rather than managing with our own Cassandra cluster it would be ideal to move with a managed solution. Decided to look for solutions others have followed to mitigate these type of limitation.

Comment: For full disclosure, I work at DataStax but if you haven't seen it already, [Astra DB](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-astra) is a fully-managed Cassandra-as-a-service which runs on public clouds including AWS. Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, now I'm looking into that. I'm trying to pick up bits and pieces using Terraform. But didn't find a way to get the Astra datacenter id using Terraform script. Could you help me with this please?